# ubuntu 14.04 Texlive 2014 getnonfreefonts-sys ! ERROR: The install directory '/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local' is not writable

Tags: fonts, texlive, installing, ubuntu

I upgraded to `Texlive 2014` on `Unbutu 14.04` and trying to install `non-freetonts` with `getnonfreefonts-sys`. This command throws the following error:

```
 ERROR: The install directory '/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local' is not writable.
```

Then I tried the following command:

```
  wget http://tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/install-getnonfreefonts
  sudo texlua install-getnonfreefonts
  getnonfreefonts -a
```

Then I used `getnonfreefonts-l` to check the installed fonts and this command shows `Webomints` font in this list.

Then I'm getting the this error

> !pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file WebOMintsGD): Font WebOMintsGD not
>   found

(Might be in different directory, looked [this link](http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/sK0ydyiOYWwpKf22YGEx) for the same problem where fonts were in different directory). I'm not very expert and struggling with it. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `sudo getnonfreefonts-sys -a`? and delete `~/.texlive2014`?

Comment: Thanks @cfr for your interest in my problem. Could you explain how to delete ~/.texlive2014? Is this will delete texlive2014?

Comment: No. It is a directory for generated files in your home directory. If it doesn't exist, don't worry about it. But if you have problems even when things are correctly installed, you may have stale files there and deleting the directory will force regeneration.

Comment: `rm -rfv ~/.texlive2014` = delete + options 'recursive', 'force', and 'verbose' = forcibly delete without prompting the target and any subfiles while telling you about each thing it deletes.  It is an easy command to misuse, so be careful with it.  (cfr's suggestion is safe, however.)

Comment: @MYaseen208 Beware of commands, if you don't understand them. Jons suggestion might be dangerous: If you add a space at the »right« place, it will delete your whole /home folder, without asking, and not just the folder ~/.texlive2014 .

Comment: @KeksDose Not quite! It would delete your own home directory, probably. But it won't delete all of `/home`. (That would include any other users' directories, too.)

Answer (score 3):

There is no need for installing `texlive` as root. It makes sense to set the owner of the `texlive` to the user:

```
sudo chown -R <username>.users /usr/local/texlive
```

Then you can run all `<command>-sys` as a default user.

Comment: Thanks @Herbert for your answer. I followed your instructions but still getting the error: `!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file WebOMintsGD): Font WebOMintsGD not found`. The output of `getnonfreefonts-sys` shows   `Directories:   temporary: '/tmp/getfont-<PID>' install:   '/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local'` and the output of `getnonfreefonts` shows `Directories: temporary: '/tmp/getfont-<PID>'  install:   '/home/yaseen/texmf'`.

Comment: Even better is to use a dedicated non-privileged user to manage the install.

Comment: @cfr: No, it is much more easier to run it as a user if it is a single user system. Then you'll never will have problems when mixing the default commands with the `-sys` extensions ...

Comment: @MYaseen208: difficult to say what happens on your system. I just tried the three commands (without szdo) to download the foints and it worked. They were installed in `/home/<user>/texmf/`

Comment: @Herbert I agree that it is easier. But it is better to use an account other than your main user account. Convenience isn't everything ;). (It is still better to follow your advice than to use the root account, though.)

Comment: @cfr: That doesn't solve the problem if a user for example mixes the call of `updmap` and `updmap-sys`

Comment: @Herbert I know. That is why it is ***easier*** to follow your advice.